# How to show a screen flow as a Listview button on any object?

Tags: custom-button, list-view, screen-flow

Actually, I know how to show a screen flow in custom action but wanted to know - Is there any mean to show a screen flow as a list view button?

and if yes then how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of today (Spring 22), there isn't a true equivalent of the Flow Quick Action for List Views, per se.

You can launch a Flow from List Views, however.

Get the Flow's URL (you can see it when you click into the Flow's Details and Versions).

[image: Flow Details and Versions]

Then, in the Object Manager, add a List button to the object, and use the flow's URL as for the button.

[image: List button in Object Manager]

And add the button to the Object's List View Buttons:

[image: Edit List View settings in Object Manager]

[image: Adding button to List Views]

There are some more advanced approaches, such as an aura lightning component with the flow embedded in it using `lightning:flow` or a Visualforce page with the flow embedded (this VF-embedded flow approach is least-ideal, as the Flow will be in classic run-time).

***Undocumented Hack Warning***

You can also get the selected record IDs into the flow if your flow has a collection variable called `ids` (all lower case- it is case sensitive). This is undocumented, but it does work and has worked for several years.

[image: 4 Records Selected in List View]

[image: 4 Selected Records in the Flow]

Comment: Thank you so much, Jeff Kranz, for such a detailed explanation; it was beneficial, and I am grateful to you for taking that much pain. Thank you so much, brother.

Comment: On Summer 22, weirdly, the only way I could get the ids value to show up in the flow was to switch the list button to "Display in existing window without sidebar or header". Otherwise the ids variable was empty

Comment: this was very helpful, and I would suggest the url be slightly improved because when the Flow interview ends, you need the user to get back to somewhere that makes sense, I used this /flow/My_Screen_Flow_Contact?retURL=003?fcf=filterName=Recent which brings the user back to the listview they started from. You can see a ton of details around page 224 in the designer guide https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/rel1/doc/en-us/static/pdf/salesforce_cloud_flow_designer_guide.pdf

Comment: @jeff How can your flow run with the lightning interface ? when i execute the flow from list view button, the flow has the classic look :(

Comment: @RobEaston the link doesn't work any more. Got any other reference other than a pdf page?