# Passing Record id to flow through list view button

Tags: visual-workflow, record

There is button placed on account list view which calls a flow, it enables user to select multiple accounts and  pass those id's to flow. now i have placed thais  list view on 'Training'(custom object) record page   i want to pass training record id to the  flow which triggers on click of button in account list view. can anyone help me ho wto pass training record id to flow? requirement is to add multiple accounts to training after selecting multiple account and clicking button we create  'training attendees' (acts like junction object)records for those accounts for that training.

Comment: check out the answer to this question here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/369271/62239

Answer (score 1):

Create a text collection variable with name "ids" and make it available for input. You will automatically get all the selected record Ids in this variable.

*Note that name of this variable is case sensitive.*

[image]

Comment: Can you add a citation of documentation to this article please?

Comment: @PhilW - I couldn't find any official documentation. I have used in my projects as well as I have seen people are using this and have posted blog on this.

Comment: Yeah, that's all I could find too.