# Launching flows in a SalesForce Community site

Tags: visual-workflow, customer-community-plus

I'm relatively new to Salesforce and I'm looking to create a button to launch a flow from a record list view page on an Experience/Community site. The idea is to allow users to select several records, then have the flow create a new object and add references to the selected records to that object.

The list button launches the flow via a call to `{!URLFOR('/flow/<myapiname>')}`

The flow and button are created, and they work well for internal users.   When I log in as a Community user the flow doesn't launch. Also, even as an internal user, when I access the record list through the Experience site the flow doesn't launch.  No errors, they just don't do anything.

I believe I have correctly configured the "Run Flows" permission for my community users' Profile.  Note that this flow is for logged in community users, not guest.

I have also set the profile for the community user so that community users have read access to my custom objects and all associated fields.

I've tried creating the flow as both a Screen Flow and an AutoTriggered flow....the flow basically performs some background tasks like record creation that does not require any user input.

What am I missing? Been banging my head for days, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Pleas [edit] your post to describe if you set the proper object and field permissions for the community users.  Also, you should capture a [debug log](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.code_debug_log.htm&type=5) in Setup > Debug Logs.  Set Workflow = FINER for your Debug Level and be sure to set the user = the community user that you are testing.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance @DavidCheng, I've updated the post with what (I hope) are some relevant additional details.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `URLFOR()` instead of just the URL itself, as [mentioned in this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/369265/how-to-show-a-screen-flow-as-a-listview-button-on-any-object)?  Also, what do you see in your debug log?

Comment: @DavidCheng - No reason specifically, other than that's what appeared in another forum answer.  I've changed it to use the direct URL -- same result.  If it set up debug logs for my community user, it still appears that the flow does not launch.